# Editing content of page having custom master page in office365 sharepoint site

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, office365

I have signed up for office 365
which provides sharepoint site.

I have created a simple master page and content page,
however i'm unable to edit the content of the page from sharepoint designer

MasterPage.master

```
<%@Master language="C#"%>
<%@ Register tagprefix="SharePoint" namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<SharePoint:RobotsMetaTag runat="server"></SharePoint:RobotsMetaTag>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="frmMain" runat="server">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphMain" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~site/MasterPage.master" inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" meta:progid="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document" meta:webpartpageexpansion="full" %>

<%@ Register tagprefix="SharePoint" namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>

<asp:Content ID="content1" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphMain">
My custom html
</asp:Content>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, either you mention the xmlns:asp="asp" and then you can edit through the web interface but not in SPD or you remove it and then you can edit in SPD but not through the web.

Comment: I posted same question at http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/15897/editing-content-of-page-having-custom-master-page-in-office365-sharepoint-site , got different answers..

Answer (score 2):

In the `default.master`, remove the property `xmlns:asp="asp"` under the `asp:Content` tag.